# IE/FF addEventListener not executing function

Tags: javascript, onchange, addeventlistener

The follow code isn't working for me in FF/IE. Chrome works. The problem seems to be that the function 'handleImage' ins't be called. What goes wrong here?

Thanks

```
    function handleImage(event) {

    console.log('Handle the image');
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (event) {
    $('#uploader img').attr('src', event.target.result);
    }

    if (event.target.files[0] != undefined) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
    imageLoaderError = false
    } else {
    imageLoaderError = true
    }
}

var imageLoader         = document.getElementById('image');
var imageLoaderError    = false;
imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);
```

Comment: any error in your browser console

Comment: No errors, FireFox 38.0.1